# Relationship between Euler characteristic of Manifold and Submanifold using Gauss-Bonnet Theorem with Boundary?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, surfaces

The Gauss-Bonnet theorem is usually seen without the geodesic curvature $k_g$ line integral, for compact manifolds M without boundary (making the Euler characteristic equal the area integral of the Gaussian curvature $K$).
That is:
$$
2\pi\chi(M)=\iint_M K dA + \int_{\partial M} k_g dS = \iint_M K dA  + 0.
$$

Let's say that I have an arbitrary 2D manifold X without boundary (as in the usual case above). Inside it, I choose a counter-clockwise-oriented closed loop (so that the tangential direction is chosen per convention), and use the Gauss-Bonnet (GB) theorem on the manifold Y dictated by the loop. Essentially, this is like choosing from the main manifold X, a submanifold Y.

How does the Euler characteristic from using the GB theorem on submanifold Y $\chi(Y)$ relate to that of the parent manifold X $\chi(X)$?
In this situation, what does the resulting Euler-characteristic mean? When will $\chi(X) = \chi(Y)$, if at all? Or, are there any other general relationships?
I guess my confusion is whether the GB theorem describes the same manifold or two different ones. For example, does the geodesic curvature integral of Y compensate for the missing area for the gaussian curvature integral, making both Euler characteristics equal?

The most I have found in the literature has been about two disjoint manifolds bounded by curves summing to equal the overall Euler character of the system.

Comment: As with your other post, you're missing a factor of $2\pi$ in Gauss-Bonnet. I recommend you explore your question yourself by considering $X$ to be the usual round sphere and the loop to be a line of latitude (not necessarily the equator). Then you have two choices of $Y$, don't you? Work out all the terms you've asked about explicitly.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for the advice. I believe that in that case, the sum of the Euler characteristics of the two halves will yield the character of the sphere. The geodesic curvature integral contributions will cancel each other due to the orientation requirement.

Comment: Yes, that's right, so you have to sum curvature/Euler characteristic over pieces to recover global information about $X$. In general, you may have more than two pieces. But it seems to me you've answered your own question(s) in the negative.